# Parsing HTML to get web links, some links show a :80 in the URL. Why is this?

Tags: java, port, jsoup

I'm using JTidy to Parse HTML pages to extract the pages links. I was testing it on a few web pages, one of them was www.support.xbox.com. Some of the links are showing a :80 in the URL e.g.

http://support.xbox.com:80/en-US/xbox-360/disc-drive/disc-replacement-program
http://support.xbox.com:80/en-US/xbox-live/marketplace-and-purchasing/play-xbox-live-content
http://support.xbox.com:80/en-US/games/call-of-duty/call-of-duty-elite-subscription

I presume the :80 indicates the port that's being used, but why is this?

Not sure if my code is needed but here it is anyways!

```
package urltest;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Connection;

public class UrlTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String url = "http://support.xbox.com";
    print("Fetching %s...", url);

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();
    Elements links = doc.select("div#BodyContent a[href]");

    print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
    for (Element link : links) {
        print("%s  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
    }
}

private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
    System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
}

private static String trim(String s, int width) {
    if (s.length() > width)
        return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
    else
        return s;
}
}
```

Comment: **80** is the port number for **http** protocol just as **443** is for **https**

Comment: But why would it appear for links on this site and no other sites?

Comment: The website itself contains such ":80" (for whatever reason) in the URLs in that case. The link Elements are treated literally so no port designator is being added or removed -- so ask the site owners. And why is this tagged "jtidy"?

Comment: (http://support.xbox.com/en-US/ has no such "issues", so it might only be some regional pages?)

Comment: I tagged it as JTidy as I was using that library and I wasn't sure if it was a quirk of the plugin.

After testing www.support.xbox.com/en-us instead of www.support.xbox.com I'm not getting any :80's in the URL. It's not an important question, I'm just wondering why as they are both the same page, www.support.xbox.com just redirects to www.support.xbox.com/en-us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go on a browser and type

> www.stackoverflow.com

or

> www.stackoverflow.com:80

you will get the same result. Because the browser implicitily adds :80 to all addresses which represent the port number for http request.

Now why is some websites adding it and some no, it depends on many issues. But after all, it won't affect your program in any way

Answer (score 1):

If you notice the redirection header:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-Control: private
Location: http://support.xbox.com:80/en-US/
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 08 Jan 2012 00:19:43 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

notice that the `Location:` field in the URL contains the port number. This is why you don't get the port number when visiting the page directly, while you got the port number while visiting the page through the redirect.

As to why the site issued a redirect with an explicit :80 port number, which should be the default anyway, you'd have to ask the site owner.